# The simplest way to implement a VPN?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, openvpn

I have a headless machine running Lubuntu that I'm using a file server. I already SSH into it, and use remote desktop from within my local network to do any maintenance I need, either on the desktop or via the terminal.

The last step, as far as I can see, is setting up a VPN. I would call myself an intermediate computer user; I can use the terminal from instructions comfortably, and understand the basics of LAN and WAN. Unfortunately, the instructions I can find for setting up a reliable VPN on Ubuntu (I believe OpenVPN) are either incomplete, incorrect or too complex. All I want is to have the VPN running on my server from startup, and use it on a laptop, mobile and tablet when out and about to access files and music.

Can anybody either help me out directly, or point me to a well-written, reliable web resource that can help me? I'm pulling my hair out...

Answer (score 0):

The Absolute Minimum Server Setup

What follows are the absolute minimum instructions that you need to get a basic `PPTP VPN` server running under `Ubuntu`. Clients will then be able to `VPN` into the server and route their internet traffic so that it goes through the server to the internet.

First, install the required software:

```
sudo apt-get install pptpd
```

Second, `enable ip_forward` in the kernel for IPv4 by uncommenting the associated line in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
sudo sed -i -r 's/^\s*#(net\.ipv4\.ip_forward=1.*)/\1/' /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Reload the config file to have the change take effect immediately.

```
sudo -i sysctl -p
```

Third, enable `NAT` (if it isn't enabled already) so that users on the private `VPN` network can have their packets routed out to the internet:

```
OUTIF=`/sbin/ip route show to exact 0/0 | sed -r 's/.*dev\s+(\S+).*/\1/'`

sudo -i iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $OUTIF --jump MASQUERADE
```

Enable NAT on boot from the rc.local script.

```
CMD="iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface $OUTIF --jump MASQUERADE"
sudo sed -i "\$i$CMD\n" /etc/rc.local
```

Note: This guide assumes you have no firewall configured on the server. If you have a firewall on the server, such as UFW, consult the relevant documentation instead.

Fourth, for each `VPN` user, create an account in the file `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets`. Replace `$USER` with the actual username you want to use for that VPN user.

```
KEY=`head -c 20 /dev/urandom | sha1sum | nawk '{print $1}'`
echo "$USER pptpd $KEY *" | sudo tee -a /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
```

Finally, you are ready to...

Comment: Thank you for this response - is there any admin software that I can use once I have installed from the terminal? Also, I do have UFW - where should have to look for the documentation? Is it just allowing the ports that VPNs typically use?